# about:version chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Если в google chrome набрать `about:version`, то внизу можно увидеть столбики, из цифр и букв.

Что это за уникальные значения? Может ли это быть уникальный номер браузера? Как эти значения получить через JS?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Navigator.userAgent` - там есть версия.
2. `Navigator.platform` - система.
3. `js` версию достать вроде как тяжело, да и бессмысленно.
4. `flash` везде теперь восемнадцатый, либо вообще нету.

Путь к исполняемому файлу и путь к профилю по понятным причинам достать нельзя. Насчёт вариантов - не знаю.

**Обновление 1**

Наконец нагуглил про варианты. Лучше всего они гуглятся по [variations chrome](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Variations&oq=Variations&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=Variations%20chrome). Изучаю. Но вроде как через js их не получишь. Но и польза от них тоже вряд ли особая есть.

**Обновление 2**

Варианты - это уникальный id для каждого установленного хрома, он используется гугловской службой поддержки для получения больших сведений о проблеме.